# How to hide/show angular-wizard steps based on conditions with previous filled in fields (model values)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a [angular-wizard](http://mgonto.github.io/angular-wizard/). I would like to hide and show angular-wizard step based on condition.

html code:

```
<section id="main_content" class="inner main-inner" ng-app="wizard-sample" ng-controller="WizardCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <wizard on-finish="finished()" >

          <wz-step title="Step One">
            <h1>Step One</h1>
             <a title="Go to Step Two" wz-next class="m-btn blue pull-right" style="margin-right: 50px">Next <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></a>
          </wz-step>

          <wz-step title="Step Two">
            <h1>Step Two</h1>
            <a title="Go to Step One" wz-previous class="m-btn blue"><i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Previous</a>
            <a title="Go to Finish" wz-next class="m-btn blue pull-right" style="margin-right: 50px">Next <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></a>
          </wz-step>

          <wz-step title="Finish">
            <h1>Finish</h1>
            <a title="Go to Step Two" wz-previous class="m-btn blue"><i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Previous</a>            
          </wz-step>

        </wizard>
      </section>
```

controller code:

```
angular.module('wizard-sample', ['mgo-angular-wizard'])
.controller('WizardCtrl', function($scope, WizardHandler) {
    $scope.finished = function() {
        alert("Wizard finished :)");
    }

    $scope.logStep = function() {
        console.log("Step continued");
    }

    $scope.goBack = function() {
        WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use `ng-hide="Your Condition Goes Here"`

Or if you mean you want to skip a step on condition you can use `wz-next="checker()"` this function will be called before calling the next element. and use `goTo()` to skip elements. Example 
 JS

```
var checker = function(){
    if(isTrue){
        WizardHandler.wizard().goTo("Widard item number or title here");
    }
}
```

HTML
    
             Next

```
      <wz-step title="Step Two">
        <h1>Step Two</h1>
        <a title="Go to Step One" wz-previous class="m-btn blue"><i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Previous</a>
        <a title="Go to Finish" wz-next="checker()" class="m-btn blue pull-right" style="margin-right: 50px">Next <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></a>
      </wz-step>

      <wz-step title="Finish">
        <h1>Finish</h1>
        <a title="Go to Step Two" wz-previous class="m-btn blue"><i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Previous</a>            
      </wz-step>
```

Comment: even when ng-hide is set on on a wz-step, it still shows in the progress bar